# Are alliances with AI permanent?

Tags: civilization-6

As the title says, I'd like to know if alliances with AI in single-player Civilization VI are permanent.

Edit: To clarify what I mean by permanent: can the AI (or the player) break the alliance at any point until the end of the game? I'd like to know if I make an Alliance with an AI, does that take them off the table as an enemy? Can I pretty much ignore them as a threat or should I still keep an eye on them because they may back-stab me later?

Comment: What do you mean by permanent? Like do they transfer between games or saves?  (You might want to update your question as well with more information as well!)

Comment: @NBN-Alex I made an edit to address your comment. Thanks!

Comment: Much better! :)

Comment: They're permanent if you set them on your team in the setup lobby (which might only be visible when making a multiplayer game, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that Alliances with AI are **not** permanent in single-player. I couldn't find how long they last for exactly, but mine expired after approximately 30 turns.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have been able to tell, the alliance lasts 30 turns and will pull you into wars with them (if either of you are declared upon). What seems to be different from Civ V is that in VI your DoF seems to be 'on hold' while the alliance is going. When you make a DoF it should time out in I believe 30 turns as well, unless it was bumped to 60, I forget sorry, but that timer doesn't seem to tick down while you are in an alliance.